# $A$-linearity of the category of $A$-modules.

Tags: category-theory, modules

Let $A$ be a noncommutative ring. I asked myself whether the category of $A$-modules is an $A$-linear category or not. I am not able to find that this is true by giving the appropriate structure. Now is it true or is it not true?

Comment: If $A$ is not commutative, then it is not true. From which direction would we multiply a module homomorphism by an $a\in A$? (Anyway, that wouldn't produce a module morphism in general.)

Comment: I too believe that it is false, but I want a proof that there is no such structure. Just saying that the "obvious" constructions don't work is not enough.

Comment: First you'll have to say what do you mean by an $A$-linear category? Because what it usually means is a category enriched over ($A$-Mod, ⊗), and $A$ must be commutative for this to make sense.

Comment: I mean by this that the hom's are all $A$-modules and the composition map are $A$-linear.

Comment: As a sidenote, while $A$-Mod isn't generally $A$-linear in any sense of the word, it's always $Z(A)$-linear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As user54748 says in comments, if $A$ is a noncommutative ring then it's not clear that there's any good meaning for "$A$-linear".

You say you mean that homsets are $A$-modules and composition is $A$-linear, but if you mean that $(a\theta)\circ\phi=a(\theta\circ\phi)$ and $\theta\circ(b\phi)=b(\theta\circ\phi)$, then this implies that $(a\theta)\circ(b\phi)$ is equal to both $ab(\theta\circ\phi)$ and $ba(\theta\circ\phi)$. Therefore $ab-ba$, and all elements in the ideal of $A$ generated by such elements, would have to act as zero. But this ideal could contain $1$, as it does in the ring of $2\times2$ matrices over a field, and so all homsets would have to be zero.

Even if you just want the homsets to be $A$-modules, with no requirement on compsition, then consider $A=M_2(\mathbb{F}_2)$, the ring of $2\times2$ matrices over the field of two elements. If $M$ is the (right) module of row vectors, then $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,M)$ has two elements, but there is no $A$-module with two elements.

Comment: Very instructive, thanks!